# How do I use some form of version control on SharePoint Designer created forms?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Is there any way to create a recoverable backup of a SharePoint Designer created list form?  I've seen references of version controlling InfoPath forms, but that is not an option in our case.

I had a complex list view form that I was working with, and SharePoint Designer crashed on save.  The form was unrecoverable.  I ended up just recreating the form from scratch.

I find that even if you maintain a copy of the editable markup outside of SharePoint, it will not allow you to reuse it in most cases.  I would imagine that the issues center around GUID re-use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things you can do:

- Save off "last working copies" as you go. Saving the entire file or
  just the section you are working on should work fine.
- Store the XSL
  externally in a Document Library with versioning turned on
- Go the Visual Studio route

When it comes right down to it, SharePoint Designer crashes when you do something it can't handle. (No excuse for it, but as it is a code generator, it can't deal with everything.) the more you use it, the less it will crash.

Comment: Thanks Marc.  I've also discovered what would have been the best way to version for the particular case I described in my question. In designer, if you select the 'All Files' object in the left hand navigation pane, you can browse to your particular list forms and an 'Export File' option exists.  There is also an 'Import File' as well, and I have confirmed that an export/import scenerio does indeed work as expected.  However, depending on how you construct your pages, different approaches may work better.

Comment: After wrestling with this, I believe I understand why versioning the list forms is more difficult than it may seem.  The primary issue is that a page's web part composition can vary greatly between versions.  If I had a previous version of the page that contained a webpart that had subsequently been deleted off of the live site via the browser, that previous page would not work correctly if I just dropped it in as-is (because it would reference a web part instance GUID that no longer existed).

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of variables in all of this. Ideally you're working on the page only in the UI or in SharePoint Designer at any given time, not both. If it's both, you can get yourself into trouble.